# EXCEL Sum up points based on placements (combine VLOOKUP and SUM)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, vlookup

e.g. I have a list of race results:

```
A    B     C     D     E    F...
NAME P.    RACE1 RACE2 RACE
abc  =?    1     3     3
bcd        3     2     4
cde        4     4     2
def        2     1     1
```

and another sheet with points for each result:

```
A     B
PLACE POINT
1     10
2     5
3     2
4     1
```

Is it possible to get the total points in sheet1 column B based on the race results in column C-E..?
Is it a connection from VLOOKUP and SUM?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's possible. You can use a SUMPRODUCT formula for that. You may use this one in column B:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:E2=$A$13:$A$16)*$B$13:$B$16)
```

Your result will look like this:

[image: SUMPRODUCT in Excel]

This is an array function. The term `C2:E2=$A$13:$A$16` will check for race 1 to 3 if it was 1st, 2nd, 3rd or 4th place. This will result in an "imaginary" array of `TRUE` and `FALSE`. For name "abc", it will look like that.

[image: Imaginary array]

Those results are then multiplied with the points from `B13:B16` and the sum is formed.

Comment: perfect, thank!
a last question: can i make a sumproduct with conditions? e.g. only sum, wenn C1:E1 <> "RACE2"?

Comment: @McBabba Yes, that is possible as well. Then formula will then turn to `=SUMPRODUCT((C2:E2=$A$13:$A$16)*$B$13:$B$16*($C$1:$E$1<>"RACE2"))`

Comment: can I also use prefix like ... $C$1:$E$1<>"RA*" ?

Comment: @McBabba `SUMPRODUCT` does not support wildcards in the same way as `SUMIF` or `SUMIFS`. But you can use some tricks. In this case, you combine it with the `LEFT` function, which will give you: `=SUMPRODUCT((C2:E2=$A$13:$A$16)*$B$13:$B$16*(LEFT($C$1:$E$1;2)<>"RA"))`

Answer (score 1):

In Excel O365, one could use:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(C2:E2,H$2:I$5,2))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `SUM` in previous versions of Excel would deal with the CSE nomore but it's worth a try.

Comment: Not sure about that, but I think I used similar formulas back then when I used Office 2013.